# Complexity of a recursive function

Tags: complexity-theory

I have a recursive function, and I'm trying to figure out it's complexity.
denote P(n) - the runtime of the function (when given the parameter n).
I know that : P(n)=n+(n-1)*P(n-1) [p(1)=1]

How can I express P(n) without using P(...) ?

Comment: If you want to understand how to solve such recursive equasions, you can read this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving . Also, I believe that your question belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/ as it is all about solving the recurrence relation `P(n)=n+(n-1)*P(n-1) [p(1)=1]` and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @Max finding the complexity of an expression is very much related to computer science and to programming in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be O(n<sup>n</sup>). Notice that if you start expanding the expression, you'll get an element with power of n increased by 1 on each iteration. This will be the dominant element so others can be dropped for the O() calculation. For a more formal solution see the link provided by @Max.